How to navigate Roku channel to another screen?
I need to make navigation in my Roku channel. I have this logic, when app starts it opens ActivationScreen. When user activates the device, it should go to RendererScreen.
I created a Task for that:
sub init()
    print "NAVIGATE: Task initialized."
    m.top.functionName = "navigateToScene"
end sub

sub navigateToScene()
    screen = createObject("roSGScreen")
    port = createObject("roMessagePort")

    screen.setMessagePort(port)
    screen.show()

    m.top.setField("currentScene", "RendererScreen")

    while (true)
        msg = wait(0, port)
        if (type(msg) = "roSGScreenEvent")
            if (msg.isScreenClosed()) 
                return
            end if   
        end if
    end while
end sub

It does change the scene, but RendererScreen is becoming empty. It's not working properly.
I created Task and then tried to RUN it inside my ActivationScreen. However, its not working.

Why the XML tag?

The xml tag was added because Roku's SceneGraph framework involves XML files to define the UI components. And maybe navigation could be done in those XML files.

I see.  Thank you.

Tip: don't include unnecessary tags. You want focussed developers. IMHO the tag XML and ROKU are not helpful to getting a quality answer.

Thank you for the tip. I also think that maybe XML tag can be removed. However, this question is about ROKU. Why you are thinking ROKU tag is not helpful?

Remember to post to me if you want a reply from me. Because "roku" is redundant and overly broad. Example, you are a car mechanic fixing a transmission. Do you tag "car" and "transmission" or just "transmission"? New users often assume they want the broadest reach for their post. You want focused (expert) readers, not generalized readers. Plus it helps others in the future find Q/A on specific tags. IMHO the "roku" tag is a "garbage can" collecting posts from everything related to Roku. That is usually not helpful. Plus very focussed tags are less likely to be downvoted, closed or ignored.

Thank you for the explanation! I see your point about focusing on more specific tags. It makes sense that narrower tags would help attract more targeted and knowledgeable readers.
